# return value from fabric task

Tags: python, fabric

My fabfile.py contains the following:

```
# simple function - no arguments and no returns
def hello():
    print "Hello World!"

# function with default argument
def goodbye(name='Anonymous'):
    print "Buh-bye world!", name

# function that does nothing
def nothingHere():
    pass

# function that take arguments and returns something
def sum(x=0, y=0):
    sum=x+y
    return sum
```

Am new to fabric. Now for the sake of clarity and understanding, I would like to understand if there is a way to collect the return value from the **sum()** function above when run as fab command.

> fab sum:x=10,y=20

So how do I see/collect the output of the above command ?

Comment: Where do you want to see/capture it - in the shell? That output could be captured by the shell if your printed the `sum` value, rather than returning it. It might be helpful to know a little bit more about what you're trying to do, in order to steer your correctly.

Comment: I understand that getting it out on the shell would simply mean printing it out. But let's say I want the function be called from inside another function in a python script. And now I would want the sum be returned to the calling function. How do I achieve it, if at all I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the primary, intended use of Fabric: to execute tasks on remote server(s). The return values are centered around this fact.

Here's a simplified version of your script that illustrates the return values from Fabric tasks:

```
from fabric.api import execute

# function that take arguments and returns something
def sum(x=0, y=0):
    sum = x + y
    return sum

# using execute to simulate the `fab <command>` command-line usage
result = execute(sum, x=5, y=10)
print(result)
```

The result is a dictionary, keyed by the host that executed the task:

```
{'<local-only>': 15}
```

If you had run this task on several remote servers, that would look something like this:

```
result = execute(sum, x=5, y=10, hosts=['host-1', 'host-2'])
print(result)
{'host-1': 15, 'host-2': 15}
```

So if you're trying to use this `sum()` function as part of a broader array of functions that might call each other, then you simply need to access the proper/desired key from the `result` value.